# Rails odd behaviour for browser language setting es-419

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, request-headers

Our application attempts to support ES variants.

To this end we capture the user_preferred_language from an incoming request in our ApplicationController.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_i18n_locale_for_unauthenticated
  ...

  def set_i18n_locale_for_unauthenticated
    users_preferred_languages = request.user_preferred_languages
    ... # Do something with the array of loacle codes
  end
end
```

Usually this works OK and the array of locale codes matches the preferences set up in the client browser.  E.g. inspecting the `user_preferred_languages` array may look like

```
[
  [0] "pt-BR",
  [1] "pt",
  [2] "en-GB",
  [3] "en",
  [4] "en-US",
  [5] "es",
  [6] "es-419"
]
```

However if the `es-419` (Lantin America Spanish) locale is anywhere except the last position then `user_preferred_languages` will return any empty array??

I am guessing that this is an issue with Rails (or Rack), or possibly two issues:

1. The parser is not correctly handling the `es-419` case as it doesn't conform to the typical `xx-YY` format.
2. Somehow, when it is the last preferred language in the list, it manages to slip through.

I haven't tried to dig out the source for this as I was hoping someone had bumped into it before and could suggest how best to handle this.  Or perhaps there is a reason why this isn't supported?

FURTHER BACKGROUD
I am using Chromium as my browser.  Looking at the request headers it seems to be passing the language settings without any issue:

```
Request Headers
  Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.2,es-419;q=0.2,es;q=0.2
  Cache-Control:no-cache
  Connection:keep-alive
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add that you use this gem, am I right? https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the http_accept_language gem. It's fixed in the current prerelease:

```
gem "http_accept_language", "~> 2.0.0.pre"
```

Your code must be adjusted:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def set_i18n_locale_for_unauthenticated
    users_preferred_languages = http_accept_language.user_preferred_languages
  end
  ...
end
```